# How do I get a bullet prefab's sprite to use the same rotation as my weapon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, topdown

I'm working on a top down concept where the gun revolves around the player and flips according to the side your crosshair is on (similar to ZERO Sievert). I'm trying to have my bullet sprite have the correct rotation when firing in relation to my players weapon.

Below is how I'm instantiating the bullet in a shooting script which fires the correct way but the sprite itself is not rotated correctly.

```
void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firingPoint.position, firingPoint.rotation);      
        Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.AddForce(firingPoint.right * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);  
    }
```

and in my weapon handling script this is my implementation of the weapon rotation, I am flipping the weapons y scale to correct the sprite for now.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RotateWeapon();
        if (crosshair.transform.position.x < 0)
        {
            FlipWeapon();
        }
    }
void RotateWeapon()
    {
        float AngleRad = Mathf.Atan2(crosshair.transform.position.y - currentWeapon.transform.position.y, crosshair.transform.position.x - currentWeapon.transform.position.x);
        float AngleDeg = (180 / Mathf.PI) * AngleRad;
        currentWeapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, AngleDeg);
    }

    void FlipWeapon()
    {
        currentScale = transform.parent.localScale;
        currentScale.y *= -1;
        currentWeapon.transform.localScale = currentScale;
    }
```

I'm currently at a standstill on how to achieve this as most resources I've come across for top down shooting have the player turning up to a full 360 degrees where my player only faces left or right and the weapon itself only has a range of motion of 180 degrees on either side before its set to flip.

Comment: When you are saying that the bullet is rotated incorrectly, is the rotation offset from the correct one, always the same or completely random?

Comment: in general you seem to call `FlipWeapon()` every physics update once the condition is met ... is that intended?

Comment: @Voidsay sorry I should've noted that! It is always the same. I currently have the bullet set to be horizontal.

Comment: @derHugo no it is not. I meant to include the same flag I use for flipping the player which is a facingRight boolean, thank you for that :D

Comment: @Drudie what components does your bullet have? Does it happen to have an animator?

Comment: @Voidsay as of right now it has a Rigidbody 2D and a Box Collider.

Comment: @Drudie This is rather peculiar. When the bullet spawns does its collider overlap another collider on the gun or the player? I would expect random results if this is the case, but I am running out of theories. Perhaps you have a custom material shader or something else that could be considered out of the ordinary. Maybe the prefab is somehow scuffed and you could try to simply rebuild it and try again.

Comment: @Voidsay Okay so I have fixed this and this is going to sound silly. I hadn't realized it but the original bullet sprite was vertical and I was setting the prefab to be rotated 90 degrees to be horizontal. What was happening is that the 90 degree rotation was being overridden on instantiation and so going back into my art software and making the sprite horizontal fixed everything. I apologize for wasting your time on such a simple thing.

Comment: @Drudie most questions have silly answers. I'm just here for the thrill of mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try and add an offset so when you Instantiate the bullet it will look something like this:

```
GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firingPoint.position, firingPoint.rotation + offset);
```

here offset will be a rotational x y z coordinate so you would want to rotate it on the z coordinate (try all of them until you fin the right one) and rotate it either -90 degrees or 90 deegrees. You might have to rotate it 180 degress but dont use 270 instead use -90. Trust me it will help in your later days in coding. Also make sure to set offset as a variable:

```
private Vector3 offset = 0, 0, -90;
```

!Remember you can change the x y z coordinates!